# On proof of weak operator closed ness of kernel of the representation

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $\pi:L^{\infty}(X,\mu)\mapsto B(\mathcal{H})$ be a representation of an abelian von Neumann algebra. Where $\mu$ is a probability measure and $\mathcal{H}$ is a seperable Hilbert space. Prove that $\text{ ker }\pi$ is weak operator closed.

Comment: What would "weak operator topology" mean on $L^\infty$?

Comment: Means thinking $L^{\infty}(X,\mu)$ sitting inside $B(L^2(X,\mu))$

Comment: Ok. And what would "representation" mean here? In terms of continuity?

Comment: Thinking the algebra as multiplication operator in $L^2(X,\mu)$

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you are asking. There are two possibilities:

- You are requiring $\pi$ to be wot continuous. In that case, $\ker\pi=\pi^{-1}(\{0\})$ is closed.
- You are not requiring $\pi$ to be wot continuous. In that case the assertion is not true. Take $X=\mathbb N$ with the counting measure. Fix a free ultrafilter $\omega$, and let $\pi:\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)\to\mathbb C$ be $\pi(x)=\lim_{n\to\omega}x_n$. Then $\pi$ is a representation, and $\ker\pi\supset c_0$. But $c_0$ is wot dense in $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$.